# Bottom line-height for a drop initial/capital letter

Tags: css

I'm working on my project of website about photography, and for some reason I want to have a drop initial/ capital letter (lettrine in french) for my texts .

My code is this one, it works fine

```
p:first-child:first-letter 
{
    float:left;
    margin: 3px 3px 0 0;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    line-height: 25px;  
    font-size: 50px;    
    color: rgb(255, 122, 0); 

}
```

The thing is I have a big space (25 px) below this capital letter and the first "regular line" because as far as I know this `line-height` is applying both on `top` and `bottom` of this letter. Is there any way to control this height properly?

I've found some threads dealing with the same king of thing, but it seems like I have to go into negative margin and i dont know if its a "clean" solution. Should I look into `vertical-align`?

Thank you very much if you've read me so far!

Here's a picture to truly understand
[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYnI8.jpg)

Comment: You should add code as a snippet (CTRL+M) in the editor. That way, we can see the problem reproduced to which we can play with... Post your HTML too.

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by controlling the height properly? What you are doing is working as designed but you might be getting confused because you are floating the first letter left which takes it out of the normal flow. Also, it's two colons `::first-letter`

Comment: for chrome, you can use line-height via rem units or line-height value of <p> X numbers of line you want to span  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZXVgO (float + vertical-align do not match ) add bg-colors, borders or shadows to see where your elements stands ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

I found out that there is already a CSS property that support the dropcap text aside from the `::first-letter` CSS property.

Or you can still use the standard CSS `::first-letter` which is more supported by other browsers.

```css
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.3449;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
}

p.test-initial::first-letter {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: orange;
  margin-right: 5px;
  
  -webkit-initial-letter: 4;
          initial-letter: 4;
}

p.test-dropcap::first-letter {
  color: #903;
  float: left;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 75px;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="test-initial">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam feugiat, urna vel aliquam facilisis, nisi augue dapibus arcu, faucibus fringilla arcu sapien nec sapien. Sed ac enim ac ligula rhoncus elementum. Curabitur id sem facilisis, semper est eget, posuere sem. Curabitur elementum dolor sed tortor malesuada, eu tempor nisi varius. Etiam lobortis, neque quis efficitur iaculis, nisi nibh rutrum sapien, non tempus dolor odio nec erat.</p>

<p class="test-dropcap"> Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas pellentesque pulvinar diam. Sed a efficitur ipsum, eu bibendum mauris. Curabitur suscipit nisi eget lacus imperdiet gravida. Aenean orci orci, sodales eget imperdiet id, ullamcorper in ante. Vivamus malesuada hendrerit iaculis. Etiam dignissim lacus turpis, vitae placerat tortor rhoncus at. Fusce porta nec tellus eget suscipit. Aenean pharetra justo mauris, non pretium nisi sollicitudin tempus.</p>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for those quick answers. Your solution seems nice, especially the <p class="test-dropcap"> . But it doesn't work when i post the code in my CSS. I think I have to define this class somewhere, but when i put <p class="test-dropcap"> in my CSS it doesn't seems to define it...

Comment: Can you show us what you have got so far when you integrate my css code?